# Trouble parsing file obtained from Dir.glob

Tags: json, ruby, parsing

I am new to ruby. Running into error while trying to parse file obtained from Dir.glob command using JSON.parse()

```
require 'json'

Dir.glob('**/*/.json').each do |f| # find all the .json file and loop each file
  puts f
  data = JSON.parse(f)
  if data['Apple'].nil?
    puts "skipping file #{f} as it does not have Apple"
    next
  end
  parsed_key= File.dirname(data['Apple'][0]['red'][0]['key'])
  puts parsed_key
end
```

`parse': 767: unexpected token at 'xyz/abc/config.json' (JSON::ParserError)

Comment: The problem is certainly that the file `xyz/abc/config.json` contains invalid JSON. Please double check and post the content of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` there is just the path, a String. If you want the contents of the file you'll need to read it first, `data = JSON.parse(File.read(f))`

Comment: I tried this too, but then I get error for obtaining parsed_key
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: The file may contain 'null' then, that's a nil in ruby.